# C: custom shell redirecting stdin and stderr to same file continues listening for input even after error occured

Tags: c, shell, file-descriptor, stderr, execvp

I'm writing a custom shell for a class, and I'm not sure why my shell program hangs after it `execvp`s and invalid command (and redirects it to the specified file as desired). The way I found I can avoid this is to add an `exit(1)` statement after the `execvp` statement (which is where the error checking occurs). Am I doing something wrong with the file descriptors or is adding an `exit(1)` fine?

code for execvp and dealing with &>, 1>, 2>, >, < redirection

```
// runs non pipe/redirection commands
void runSimple(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    int i = 0;
    int fd;

    if (pid < 0) // error
    {
        printf("An error occured while forking child for runSimple.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) // child
    {
        // fflush(stdin);
        // fflush(stdout);
        // fflush(stderr);

        // loop and deal with special operators
        while (args[i])
        {
            printf("%s\n", args[i]);
            // deal with &>
            if (!strcmp(args[i], "&>"))
            {
                fd = creat(args[i + 1], 0644);
                if (fd < 0)
                {
                    perror("open");
                    exit(1);
                }

                dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
                close(fd);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }

            // deal with 2>
            if (args[i] && !strcmp(args[i], "2>"))
            {

                fd = creat(args[i + 1], 0644);
                if (fd < 0)
                {
                    perror("open");
                    exit(1);
                }
                dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
                close(fd);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }

            // deal with > and 1>
            if (args[i] && (!strcmp(args[i], ">") || !strcmp(args[i], "1>")))
            {
                fd = creat(args[i + 1], 0644);
                if (fd < 0)
                {
                    perror("runSimple: error opening argument for >");
                    exit(1);
                }
                dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO); // make child's stdout into file
                close(fd);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }

            // deal with <, making sure to check if args[i] exists first
            if (args[i] && !strcmp(args[i], "<"))
            {
                fd = open(args[i + 1], O_RDONLY);
                if (fd < 0)
                {
                    perror("runSimple: error opening argument for <");
                    exit(1);
                }
                dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(fd);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }

            i++;
        }

        // exec input with appropriate fd
        execvp(args[0], args);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(1);
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

`runSimple` is a function where `args` is the single input of a list of strings of each token command to run. Eg, `args` could be `["ls", '-al", "&>", "outputFile"]`(this works currently because there's no error. The program freezes when there is an error, eg args is: `["asdfsdf", "&>", "outputFile"]`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, show the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: updated the post with relevant code

Comment: When you don't have `exit` the child process continues running after the failed `execvp` call and then calls `waitpid` and blocks. At the same time, the parent is also blocked on `waitpid` and hence both "hang". Putting an `exit` there is the right thing to do.

Comment: How come for the other commands, `execvp` doesn't hang? For eg, the code for `2>` redirects `stderr` to fileName, but it doesn't hang if I input an invalid command.